# rails db:migrate causing Errno::ECONNRESET, Connection reset by peer during capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, capistrano

We are having an issue with ssh level connection error, seems to be a timeout, during long deployments running our capistrano deploy with a large rails db migration task.  Our only help has been moving these to rake tasks we manually run after deploy, not ideal.  Any ideas within ruby/rails stack or outside to ensure ssh connection stays alive?

```
Errno::ECONNRESET, Connection reset by peer
```

Full trace:

```
** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Errno::ECONNRESET, Connection reset by peer - recvfrom(2)
/Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/buffered_io.rb:65:in `recv': Connection reset by peer - recvfrom(2) (Errno::ECONNRESET)
  from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/buffered_io.rb:65:in `fill'
  from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:237:in `block in postprocess'
  from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:233:in `each'
  from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:233:in `postprocess'
  from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/processable.rb:33:in `block in process_iteration'
  from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/processable.rb:45:in `block in ensure_each_session'
  from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/processable.rb:43:in `each'
  from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/processable.rb:43:in `ensure_each_session'
  from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/processable.rb:31:in `process_iteration'
  from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/command.rb:171:in `block (2 levels) in process!'
  from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/command.rb:170:in `loop'
  from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/command.rb:170:in `block in process!'
  from /Users/Ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
  from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/command.rb:169:in `process!'
```

Comment: Note two things, I have tried as my Mac OSX user to put a .ssh/config file with:              
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 120                 and I also am using net-ssh (>= 2.9.2) ruby gem which I think is used during deploy

Answer (score 2):

"Connection reset by peer" usually means that either the software on the remote end of the connection has crashed, or else some stateful firewall between the client and the server is interfering with the TCP connection.

In this case, the remote software ought to be the SSH server. And you say that this happens on long deployments. Given these things, I'd suspect that you have a NAT device or other stateful firewall between the client and the server, and it's dropping the TCP connection after some period.

You could try setting your client to send keepalive packets. I'm not a Ruby developer, but [this page](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH.html) describes a keepalive option. Aside from that, you should talk to your network engineers to see if anything can be done about the device which is interfering with the connection.

Answer (score 2):

So hopefully this helps someone else, think I found answer to my own question.

In our situation we had web and worker boxes both getting new deployment via capistrano.  The web boxes were doing more expensive long running tasks like assets compile and publish to AWS S3 bucket.  While this was happening our worker boxes became idle and timed out from no activity.  capistrano detected this as an overall failure and rolls back release.

There are a few options here, like compiling rails asset pipeline resources ahead of time and even publishing to aws first, then starting other deployment steps.

We opt'd to just have our server's do client ping keep alives at ssh level

sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
Add these two lines to file:
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 200

Note some sites mention just the first one, I found it didnt' work well unless putting second one also, as I suspect default max count is low.

ensure to restart ssh service after the change on each deployment target machine.

Answer (score -1):

Just run rake db:migrate on your project before deploying it on server and after that run rake production deploy.